# QT 5.2 'QObject' is an ambiguous base of FilmInput

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to use 'QMetaObject' to print the information in a 'Film' class using the function in another class  called 'FilmWriter' drawing information from a GUI coded in a third class, 'FilmInput'.

However, ever since I added the Q_PROPERTIES in the base Film class, I am getting an "'QObject' is an ambiguous base of FilmInput'" error message located in both lines where I connected the QPushButtons to the Print_Data() and quit() functions.

My Film.h file:

```
#ifndef FILM_H
#define FILM_H

#include <QDate>
#include <QObject>

class Film : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString title READ getTitle WRITE setTitle)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString director READ getDirector WRITE setDirector)
    Q_PROPERTY(QDate releaseDate READ getReleaseDate WRITE setDate)
    Q_PROPERTY(int length READ getLength WRITE setLength)

public:
    Film();
    Film(QString MN, QString DIR, int LEN, QDate RD);

    void setTitle(QString t);
    void setDirector(QString dir);
    void setDate(QDate rd);
    void setLength(int len);

    QString getTitle() const;
    QString getDirector()const;
    QDate getReleaseDate() const;
    int getLength() const;

private:
    QString title;
    QString director;
    QDate releaseDate;
    int length;
};
#endif // FILM_H
```

My Film.cpp file

```
#include "film.h"

//basic constructor
Film::Film()
{
    title = QString();
    director = QString();
    releaseDate = QDate();
    length = 0;
}
//overloaded constructor
Film::Film(QString MN, QString DIR, int LEN, QDate RD)
{
    title = MN;
    director = DIR;
    releaseDate = RD;
    length = LEN;
}

//4 accessors
QString Film::getTitle() const
{
    return title;
}

QString Film::getDirector() const
{
    return director;
}

QDate Film::getReleaseDate() const
{
    return releaseDate;
}

int Film::getLength() const
{
    return length;
}

//4 setters
void Film::setTitle(QString t)
{
    title = t;
}

void Film::setDirector(QString dir)
{
    director = dir;
}

void Film::setDate(QDate rd)
{
    releaseDate = rd;
}

void Film::setLength(int len)
{
    length = len;
}
```

My FilmInput.h file:

```
#ifndef FILMINPUT_H
#define FILMINPUT_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>

#include <QLabel>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QDateEdit>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLine>

#include "film.h"
#include <filmwriter.h>

class FilmInput : public QApplication, public Film, public FilmWriter
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FilmInput(int argc, char* argv[]);

    void obtain_Film_Data();

public slots:
    //creating a SLOT function
    void Print_Data();

private:
    //initializing an Object of Type Film
    Film T2;

    //creating the pointers for the input boxes
    QLineEdit *NMX;
    QSpinBox *LENX;
    QLineEdit *DIRX;
    QDateEdit *RDX;

};
#endif // FILMINPUT_H
```

My FilmInput.cpp file:

```
#include "filminput.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

FilmInput::FilmInput(int argc, char* argv[]) : QApplication(argc, argv)
{
    QWidget *w = new QWidget;
    w->resize(350,200);
    w->setWindowTitle("Film Data");
    w->show();

    //create Headers
    QLabel *NML = new QLabel("Name of Movie:");
    QLabel *DIRL = new QLabel("Name of Director");
    QLabel *LENL = new QLabel("Length:");
    QLabel *RDL = new QLabel("Release Date:");

    //initializing the input functions
    NMX = new QLineEdit;
    LENX = new QSpinBox;
    DIRX = new QLineEdit;
    RDX = new QDateEdit;

    //create Buttons
    QPushButton *Print = new QPushButton("Print"); //Prints/saves to File
    QPushButton *Exit = new QPushButton("Exit"); //closes Program. Just adding for convenience

    //creating a grid to build the layout
    QGridLayout *Grid1 = new QGridLayout;

    //placing labels, buttons and input slots in the grid
    Grid1->addWidget(NMX,0,1);
    Grid1->addWidget(NML,0,0);
    Grid1->addWidget(DIRX,1,1);
    Grid1->addWidget(DIRL,1,0);
    Grid1->addWidget(LENX,2,1);
    Grid1->addWidget(LENL,2,0);
    Grid1->addWidget(RDX,3,1);
    Grid1->addWidget(RDL,3,0);
    Grid1->addWidget(Print,4,3);
    Grid1->addWidget(Exit,5,3);

    w->setLayout(Grid1);

    //connecting the 2 Buttons
    w->connect(Print,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Print_Data()));  //Error found here
    w->connect(Exit,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(quit()));         //Error found here

}

void FilmInput::obtain_Film_Data()
{
    T2.setDirector(DIRX->text());
    T2.setTitle(NMX->text());
    T2.setLength(LENX->value());
    T2.setDate(RDX->date());
}

//setting up the SLOT function
    //Print_Data will run the obtain_Film_Data function to get the data, then runs the saveFilm
    //Function to print it to the file
void FilmInput::Print_Data()
{
    obtain_Film_Data();
    saveFilm();
}
```

My FilmWriter.h file:

```
#ifndef FILMWRITER_H
#define FILMWRITER_H

#include "film.h"

#include <QObject>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QVariant>

class FilmWriter: public Film
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FilmWriter();

    void saveFilm(/*Film f*/ QObject *f);

};

#endif // FILMWRITER_H
```

my FilmWriter.cpp file:

```
#include "filmwriter.h"

FilmWriter::FilmWriter()
{

}

void FilmWriter::saveFilm(/*Film f*/ QObject *f)
{

    //create a text file to store the data if there isn't one already present. It will be found in the 'build' file
    //new Data will be added at the end of the file
    QFile Text_File_Name("Saved_Movie_Data.txt");
    Text_File_Name.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Append|QIODevice::Text);

    //storing the Data in the File
    QTextStream Text_Out(&Text_File_Name);
    QMetaObject Data = f->metaObject();
    for(int i = Data->propertyOffset();i<Data->propertyCount(); i++)
    {
        const QMetaProperty prop = Data->property(i);
        QString name = prop.name();
        QVariant value = prop.read(Data);
        QString valStr = value.toString();
    }
    //below is old code from before trying to use QMetaObject class
//    Text_Out <<endl << endl << "Movie Name: " << f.getTitle() << endl;
//    Text_Out << "Director Name: " << f.getDirector() << endl;
//    Text_Out << "Movie Length: " << f.getLength() << " Minutes" << endl;
//    Text_Out << "Release Date: " << f.getReleaseDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd") << endl;

    //closing the text file
    Text_File_Name.close();
}
```

lastely my main.cpp file which I use to get the program going

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "filminput.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FilmInput app(argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

as mentioned above, QT creator detects an error in the two 'connect' functions in the FilmInput.cpp file.
Could anyone tell me how to resolve those 2 issues please?

Comment: FilmInput inherits QObject twice, once from Film, and once from QApplication. When you use QObject functions then, it doesn't know which QObject base you mean. Inheriting QApplication seems weird, it is usually created in main function, you could also switching from inheritance to composition and hold objects as members of class instead of inheriting.

Comment: That's a really confusing class hierarchy. A class with input in the name inherits from a class with writer in the name, everything inherits from Film at least once but some also have Film member variables.